# Touchpad nearly inactive in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, asus

I have a laptop ASUS X550LD. When I installed Ubuntu 14.04 I had to use my keyboard. The mousepad is nearly unresponsive, like when I rollover too fast the cursor moves a bt few seconds later. I increased the speed from 'mouse and touchpad settings'. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is

In your `/etc/default/grub`, replace

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

with this

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash psmouse.proto=bare"`

Then,

`sudo update-grub`

Reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the touchpad driver :

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```